# CreateProcessAsUser fails with error 1314 even when correct privileges are set

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-security

I keep getting error 1314 from CreateProcessAsUserW regardless to what privileges i set, according to MSDN i should add **SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME** & **SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME**.

Just to make sure, i verified in the group policy console that the privileges were actually added.

```
LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
WCHAR* SystemName = &strSessionUserName[0];
USHORT SystemNameLength;
LSA_UNICODE_STRING lusSystemName;
NTSTATUS ntsResult;
LSA_HANDLE lsahPolicyHandle;

// Object attributes are reserved, so initialize to zeros.
ZeroMemory(&ObjectAttributes, sizeof(ObjectAttributes));

//Initialize an LSA_UNICODE_STRING to the server name.
SystemNameLength = (USHORT)wcslen(SystemName);
lusSystemName.Buffer = SystemName;
lusSystemName.Length = SystemNameLength * sizeof(WCHAR);
lusSystemName.MaximumLength = (SystemNameLength + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

// Get a handle to the Policy object.
ntsResult = LsaOpenPolicy(
    nullptr,    //Name of the target system.
    &ObjectAttributes, //Object attributes.
    0x000f0fff, //Desired access permissions.
    &lsahPolicyHandle  //Receives the policy handle.
    );

PSID pSid;
if (false == ConvertStringSidToSid(strSid.data(), &pSid))
    return false;

WCHAR* pQuotaName = L"SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege";
LSA_UNICODE_STRING Privilege[1];
size_t stQuotaLength = wcslen(pQuotaName);
Privilege[0].Buffer = pQuotaName;
Privilege[0].Length = (USHORT)(stQuotaLength*sizeof(WCHAR));
Privilege[0].MaximumLength = (USHORT)(stQuotaLength + 1)*sizeof(WCHAR);
ntsResult = LsaAddAccountRights(lsahPolicyHandle, pSid, Privilege, 1);

if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
    NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
    L"SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege",   // privilege to lookup 
    &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
{
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
    hToken,
    FALSE,
    &tp,
    sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
    (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
    (PDWORD)NULL))
{
    printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}


WCHAR* pAssignToken = L"SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege";
size_t stAssignToken = wcslen(pAssignToken);
Privilege[0].Buffer = pAssignToken;
Privilege[0].Length = (USHORT)(stAssignToken*sizeof(WCHAR));
Privilege[0].MaximumLength = (USHORT)(stAssignToken + 1)*sizeof(WCHAR);
ntsResult = LsaAddAccountRights(lsahPolicyHandle, pSid, Privilege, 1);

if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
    NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
    L"SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege",   // privilege to lookup 
    &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
{
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
    hToken,
    FALSE,
    &tp,
    sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
    (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
    (PDWORD)NULL))
{
    printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}


WCHAR* pTcbName = L"SeTcbPrivilege";
size_t stTcbName = wcslen(pTcbName);
Privilege[0].Buffer = pTcbName;
Privilege[0].Length = (USHORT)(stTcbName*sizeof(WCHAR));
Privilege[0].MaximumLength = (USHORT)(stTcbName + 1)*sizeof(WCHAR);
ntsResult = LsaAddAccountRights(lsahPolicyHandle, pSid, Privilege, 1);

if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
    NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
    L"SeTcbPrivilege",   // privilege to lookup 
    &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
{
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
    hToken,
    FALSE,
    &tp,
    sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
    (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
    (PDWORD)NULL))
{
    printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

if (FALSE == CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, nullptr, L"notepad.exe", nullptr, nullptr, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
{
    return false;
}
```

I use the following flags to retrieve the token from the target user:

```
TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY
```

[image]

Using **CreateProcessWithToken** / **CreateProcessWithLogon** is problematic, As CreateProcessWithToken kicks in a new job, which messes up the initializion of the target process, and CreateProcessWithLogon requires password, which is unknown during runtime.

Comment: Failing to enable a privilege isn't an error wrt the `AdjustTokenPrivileges` call itself. Check whether `GetLastError()` is either `ERROR_SUCCESS` or `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`. Anyway, `CreateProcessAsUser` enables privileges on demand. They just need to be present, not necessarily enabled, in the token of the calling process (not the target `hToken`). Assigning the privilege to the account via `LsaAddAccountRights` isn't of any help until a new token is created. Privileges can be enabled, disabled, removed, but not added to a token.

Comment: In other words, add the privileges to the account your code is running in *first*, then reboot, *then* try CreateProcessAsUser.  (In production, the best solution is usually to run code that needs CreateProcessAsUser as a service, configured to run as local system.  That way you don't need to mess with the privilege assignments at all.)

Comment: @eryksun, Actually after applying that code, i was able to see through gpedit.msc that priveleges had been actually added to the secondary account.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I've heard about starting this as a service, after your approval regarding this, I'm going to try this.

Comment: @igalk: gpedit.msc only tells you what privileges an account will have *the next time it is logged in*.  It doesn't tell you anything about existing processes.  Also, if by "secondary account" you mean the account you're trying to launch the child process in, that's wrong; you need to assign the privileges to the account that the parent process (the one calling CreateProcessAsUser) is using.

Comment: I can't imagine why `hToken` would need the privileges. Maybe you're currently impersonating, but `CreateProcessAsUser` impersonates self precisely because it doesn't expect an impersonated client to have the required privileges to set the process token and quotas in the `NtCreateUserProcess` system call. Notice that the remarks state: `CreateProcessAsUser` must be able to open the primary token of the *calling process* with the `TOKEN_DUPLICATE` and `TOKEN_IMPERSONATE` access rights (emphasis mine).